# How to detect Outlook read receipt mail?

Tags: vba, outlook, internationalization, receipt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUh1G.jpg)

A read receipt request mail is generally indicated by a subject having a prefix "read: ", of a received mail.
However, this prefix can constitute international characters, depending on the country of origin of the received mail.

Hence, VBA codes like,
instr("read: ", mailitem.subject)
would obviously fail the test, for e-mails with non-english locales.

How do I detect read receipt mails via VBA code, without checking the mail subject?

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the `MessageClass` property of the item. See [Item Types and Message Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/item-types-and-message-classes?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for the list of well-known message classes.

Most probably it will be represented by the [ReportItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/outlook-vba/articles/reportitem-object-outlook?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm3007)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) object. The `ReportItem` object is similar to a `MailItem` object, and it contains a report (usually the non-delivery report) or error message from the mail transport system.
Unlike other Microsoft Outlook objects, you cannot create this object.

Report items are created automatically when any report or error in general is received from the mail transport system.

Answer (score 1):

For a read email notification, you will get a `ReportItem` object. In the particular case of a read notification, the `MessageClass` property will be "`Report.IPM.Note.IPNRN"`.